# How to save a query in SQL Server so it is visible in Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, view

I am SQL Server newbie, many of my thnkings are based on Access DB work.

I have searched for an answer to this question but have not found anything that answers it.

I have opened my query builder and when I close it - it asks to 'save as' and takes me to a folder. I save it but the query is not visible in object explorer, so how do I have access to it and how can I use it for making forms with InfoPath etc.

I have been searching all day and yet no results so I would be grateful for an explaination on how this can be done. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot save `Query` on `SQL Server`. It's better to create a `View` if you're planning to use it later

Comment: Of course, views can't have a default ordering, IIRC, so his query might not work there.

Comment: Well, OP is from `MS Access`, I think he meant a simple `SELECT` query

Comment: I was refering to `ORDER BY`, sorry I wasn't being clearer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx => The `SELECT` clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:
An `ORDER BY` clause, unless there is also a `TOP` clause in the select list of the `SELECT` statement ... <=  often simple select queries do have an `ORDER BY` clause..  of course the OP could use a SQL Function, which (also IIRC) doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: @JayC - A `SELECT ... FROM dbo.Function()` isn't guaranteed to return the result in any particular order either without an `ORDER BY`

Comment: Many thanks for all your replies. Your replies show that I can create new views which will act as simple select queries but with user inout filters.

I need the queries to be filters so by selecting from a drop down menu, a user can limit the data to the selected data.

Also can someone point me in the right direction on how I can make forms for users to see the data, InfoPath is too dense for me at the moment and need something less weighty if possible?

Comment: @user2083178 That's a subject for another question.